# IE debugger: How to break at any JavaScript code execution?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, internet-explorer, frontend

In Internet Explorer, is it possible to add breakpoint, which would break the execution on any JavaScript code?

I'm debugging weird behavior in HTML page and suspect *some* JavaScript callback is causing it. Actually, the weird behavior doesn't occur if I turn the JavaScript off. However, I don't know what the callback is and where it is set. Thus it would be useful to break at any JavaScript code execution after performing the weird behavior causing action to trace the bug. Is that possible in Internet Explorer debugger?

Also, I need to be able turn this "general" breakpoint on and off at will after the page have initially loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hope we can do with the breakpoints in IE as well.. Using the developer options.. 
If you've any doubt in that, please refer the following link to get clear on it.

https://raygun.com/blog/debug-javascript-internet-explorer/